# 'payable in like kind'? 'non-electing' shares?

Tags: corporate-law, legal-terms, finance, shareholders, incorporation

> each share of Series B Preferred Stock shall, by virtue of such
>   transaction and on the same terms as apply to the holders of Common
>   Stock, be converted into or exchanged for the aggregate amount of
>   shares, securities, cash or other property (***payable in like kind***)
>   receivable by a holder of the number of shares of Common Stock into
>   which such shares of Series B Preferred Stock could have been
>   converted immediately prior to such transaction if such holder of
>   Common Stock failed to exercise any rights of election as to the kind
>   or amount of shares, securities, cash or other property receivable
>   upon such transaction (provided that, if the kind or amount of shares,
>   securities, cash or other property receivable upon such transaction is
>   not the same for each non-electing share, then the kind and amount of
>   shares, securities, cash or other property receivable upon such
>   transaction for each non-electing share shall be the kind and amount
>   so receivable per share by a plurality of ***non-electing shares***).

Kindly explain the terms in ***Bold&Italic***.

Answer (score 2):

This excerpt is a little bit hard to parse without knowing what kind of transaction is being referred to, but I will give it a shot.

**payable in kind** means paid in property with no easily established monetary value, instead of stock or money or securities.

For example, my uncle was once a shareholder in a wild rice distributor that ceased to be economically viable as a going concern because it couldn't sell its inventory for a reasonable price. So, it wound up its business and dissolved itself. But, rather than selling the warehouse full of wild rice it had left at a fire sale price when the market was weak and distributing cash to its shareholders, it instead, after paying its creditors with the proceeds of all of its cash and assets other than wild rice, made a liquidating distribution in which shareholders received X pounds of rice per share. My uncle's share of the inventory was roughly a UPS Van filled to the brim with wild rice, some of which he kept for personal consumption, some of which he held for sale when the price of wild rice recovered, and some of which he distributed in forty gallon lots to almost everyone in his extended family. My own family's forty gallons lasted us about fifteen or twenty years.

**non-electing shares** This contemplates that there can be a transaction in some classes of stock can elect to participate and others may not, such as a partial liquidation of the company. Non-electing shares don't participate in the plan, while electing shares do.

For example, perhaps electing shares get cash but not very much, while non-electing shares get an in kind distribution of the remaining shares.

Comment: so the 'like' in 'payable in like kind' is redundant? Excellent anecdote, by the way 

Comment: The word "like" in "payable in like kind" is a reference to what is payable in kind on account of common stock shares. So, if common shares are getting wild rice for their shares, the preferred shares must also get wild rice, rather than barley or turnips.

Comment: You would have to know the exact situation but the Like Kind part is wrong.

Comment: @Putvi On what basis do you say that?

Comment: I am not sure what the OP is doing exactly, but Payable in Kind in real estate and stocks normally relates to the tax structure.

Comment: @Putvi You are thinking about a like kind exchange under Internal Revenue Code § 1031 and related provisions, but that is not what is referred to in the language in the question.

Comment: That is what it is referring to. https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/like-kind-exchanges-now-limited-to-real-property It is listed right by the real estate part.

Comment: @Putvi You are incorrect. "Payable in like kind" in a corporate document is not the same as a "like kind exchange" under IRC § 1031. They are two completely different concepts.

Comment: No, thats exactly what it means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92480/discussion-between-ohwilleke-and-putvi).

Comment: Anyway, it is referring to the thing in the link from the IRS.

Comment: There is no such thing as a like kind exchange of property for stock under the Internal Revenue Code so it can't be a like kind exchange. Like kind exchanges involve a seller, a first buyer and a purchase by the original seller, of real estate (or certain other tangible personal property) in transactions with third-parties, not shareholders.

Comment: The tangible property part is just a common way of doing it. In banking and securities it gets converted to debt.

Comment: And non electing shares normally refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-voting_stock.

Comment: @Putvi You aren't allowed to do like kind exchanges of intangible property such as stock as a matter of tax law. And Non-electing shares almost never refers to "Non-voting stock". Instead, "non-electing shares" means shares that don't participate in a particular transaction or fail to elect particular treatment in that transaction. I can't think of a single instance in which non-voting stock has been referred to as a non-electing share.

Comment: In most large publicly listed companies it refers to votes. Check SEC filings.

Comment: "Non-electing" shares almost never refers to "non-voting" shares in SEC filings. If you read an SEC filing thinking that this is what is means, you are mistaken.

Comment: What? Its used in all sorts of companies SEC filings....

Comment: @putvi Not with the meaning you give to that term. Provide an example to the contrary.

Comment: Look at Target, Exxon Mobile, any Biotech.

Answer (score -2):

The term "payment in kind", when used by a public company, normally refers to payment in kind notes. It allows the company to pay with securities, like stocks, rather than money. It can also refer to using physical goods or services to settle debts, but that is not the most widely used method for public companies.

> Payment-in-kind also refers to a financial instrument that pays interest or dividends to investors of bonds, notes, or preferred stock with additional securities or equity instead of cash. Payment-in-kind securities are attractive to companies preferring not to make cash outlays and they are often used in leveraged buyouts.
>   https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/paymentinkind.asp

Payment in kind loans were popular in leveraged buyouts:

> In leveraged buyouts, PIKs is used if the purchase price of the target exceeds leverage levels up to which lenders are willing to provide a senior loan, a second lien loan, or a mezzanine loan, or if there is no cash flow available to service a loan (e.g., due to dividend or merger restrictions). It is typically provided to the acquisition vehicle, either another company or a special purpose entity (SPE), and not to the target itself.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIK_loan

The term non- electing shares can vary a bit from place to place, but it generally refers to a shareholder who did not exercise the right to vote. https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/non-electing-shareholder

Sometimes, it is used in reference to stock that does not offer voting rights, but technically, that would be non- voting stock.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-voting_stock